# Illegal instruction: 4 while practicing buffer overflow

Tags: c, macos, buffer-overflow

I was trying to practice buffer overflow on c using MacBook Pro (2019), but I got Illegal instruction: 4 error while executing the code.

Code (overflow_example.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int value = 5;
    char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8];
    
    strcpy(buffer_one, "one");  /* Put "one" into buffer_one. */
    strcpy(buffer_two, "two");  /* Put "two" into buffer_two. */
    
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
    
    printf("\n[STRCPY] copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n", strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]);    /* Copy first argument into buffer_two. */
    
    printf("[AFTER] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[AFTER] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
}
```

Input:

gcc -o overflow_example. overflow_example.c

./overflow_example 1234567890

Expected behavior:

[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0x7ff7b4b6f8a8 and contains 'two'

[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0x7ff7b4b6f8b0 and contains 'one'

[BEFORE] value is at 0x7ff7b4b6f894 and is 5 (0x00000005)

[STRCPY] copying 10 bytes into buffer_two

[AFTER] buffer_two is at 0x7ff7b4b6f8a8 and contains '12345678'

[AFTER] buffer_one is at 0x7ff7b4b6f8b0 and contains '90'

[AFTER] value is at 0x7ff7b4b6f894 and is 5 (0x00000005)

Actual behavior:

[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0x7ff7b79fc8a8 and contains 'two'

[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0x7ff7b79fc8b0 and contains 'one'

[BEFORE] value is at 0x7ff7b79fc894 and is 5 (0x00000005)

[STRCPY] copying 10 bytes into buffer_two

Illegal instruction: 4

Comment: You are overflowing an array allocated in the stack, which corrupts (or would have corrupted) the data in the stack, hence your program simply terminates. You may get away with this if you allocate your buffers in the heap, if your overflow happens to not attempt to overwrite something important.

Comment: The code assumes that the first byte of `buffer_one` is immediately after the last byte of `buffer_two`. Nothing in the C standard guarantees that. You'll need to step through the assembly code with a debugger to see what's actually happening.

Comment: if you want some kind of guarantee of the order of variables, you can put them in a struct

Comment: I have tried using struct and reversed buffer_one and buffer_two to guarantee the orders but illegal instruction 4 still pops up. Also, shouldn't the error message I get be a Segmentation fault if the program terminates?

Comment: You are probably overwriting the return address from main on the stack. This might cause the execution to jump to an address that doesn't have a valid instruction. This the Illegal instruction error